# How to link 2 seperate Excel sheets in 2 different PC using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm starting up a new project which involves 2 PC. One PC will have an Excel sheet used for data entry. And another will have another Excel sheet used for displaying data from data entry. These 2 PC will be connected to a server and will be using the same version of Excel.

What I'm planning now is to get the display to detect changes in data entry frequently so that data is accurate. I know for a fact that this can work if both files are open in the same PC using VBA.

However, I can't figure out how do this if both files are on separate PC. Is it even possible to do it simply with VBA or do I need something else to help me?

Comment: Create a routine that updates the display sheet. Schedule it to run at a given interval to update and it is possible with using just VBA.

Comment: you could post the data to a web page, then use the other PC to scrape the data

Comment: "These 2 PC will be connected to a server" - what kind of server do you mean here?  File server ? Web server ?

Comment: File server. Sorry for lack of details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

After digging further online and some changes I came up with this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Read()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim src As Workbook

' open data entry in read-only
Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\EXCEL MONITORING FILE.xlsx", True, True)

' count rows from data entry
Dim iTotalRows As Integer
iTotalRows = src.Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count

' copy data.
Dim iCnt As Integer         
For iCnt = 1 To iTotalRows
    Worksheets("Display").Range("A1:W1" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:W1" & iCnt).Formula
Next iCnt

' close data entry read only.
src.Close False             
Set src = Nothing

ErrHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Now it works fine.